# How to auto increment an alpha numeric id in Java

Tags: java, string, alphanumeric

I want to implement a functionality that auto increment an alpha numeric id in a Java program.

The ids types are Strings, have only digits and lower case latin letters, and is case insensitive.

Basically, I want a function called `static String next(String id)` that gives what should be the next id.

The id should increase from right to left, and new characters should be added on the left.

For example

```
assertEquals("1", IdUtils.next("0"));
assertEquals("a", IdUtils.next("9"));
assertEquals("10", IdUtils.next("z"));
assertEquals("10", IdUtils.next("0z"));
assertEquals("100", IdUtils.next("zz"));
assertEquals("zz1", IdUtils.next("zz0"));
assertEquals("zza", IdUtils.next("zz9"));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be helpful to show us an example of the data, no?

Comment: Could you provide examples of inputs/outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number with digits and lower case latin letters is a base-36 number, which is an extension of base-16, also known as hex.

So to increment the base-36 number, parse it, increment it, and convert back to text.

```java
static String next(String id) {
    return Long.toString(Math.incrementExact(Long.parseLong(id, 36)), 36);
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(next("0"));
System.out.println(next("9"));
System.out.println(next("z"));
System.out.println(next("zzzzzz"));
System.out.println(next("dif5613ug"));
System.out.println(next("1y2p0ij32e8e6"));
System.out.println(next("1y2p0ij32e8e7")); // Long.MAX_VALUE, so will overflow
```

*Output*

```
1
a
10
1000000
dif5613uh
1y2p0ij32e8e7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have an "current ID" variable that you increment, then it's better to keep that state in an `AtomicLong` instead of a `String`.  It's faster, and much easier to make thread-safe:

```
... 
AtomicLong m_nextId = new AtomicLong();

static String next() {
    long idnum = m_nextId.getAndIncrement();
    return Long.toString(idnum,36);
}
```

Comment: And it should be faster to compare. A long is 8 bytes, which is a lot of ids.

Comment: Thank you, I will search about AtomicLong